GitHub Actions workflow stuck
I have configured a GitHub Actions workflow and created a check for the workflow to pass before any PR can be merged.
Below is my ci.yaml:
name: Combined Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [master, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master, develop]

concurrency:
  # Cancel older, in-progress jobs from the same PR, same workflow.
  # use run_id if the job is triggered by a push to ensure
  # push-triggered jobs do not get canceled.
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  foundry-test:
    name: Foundry Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: recursive

      - name: Install Foundry
        uses: foundry-rs/foundry-toolchain@v1

      - name: Run tests
        id: run_tests
        run: forge test -vvv

      - name: Run snapshot
        run: forge snapshot

  ape-test:
    name: Ape Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.9]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run Ape tests
        id: run_ape_tests
        run: ape test -s

The CI status for some reason is never successful. What am I missing?
Git CI Action
I tried to set the CI status with my personal access token (PAT) using below code:
  set-ci-status:
    name: Set CI Status on Success
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [foundry-test, ape-test]
    if: ${{ always() }}
    steps:
      - name: Set CI status on success
        if: ${{ success() }}
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          script: |
            github.rest.repos.createCommitStatus({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              sha: context.sha,
              state: 'success',
              target_url: process.env.GITHUB_RUN_URL,
              description: 'All tests passed',
              context: 'ci status'
            });


But GitHub requires that the CI status should be reported by GitHub app not using PAT.
Git CI snap

You may need to update your repository branch protection rules. Here are some references that might help: reference 1 and reference 2.

When you set the branch protection rules in the repository's settings page, you can select which workflows are considered mandatory. In the case you posted, it seems GitHub is trying to find a job named ci status, which is not present in the code you posted-
If what you mean to do is run another workflow, you should find the corresponding .yaml file and make sure that the branch protection rule targets the exact name of that job. The exact name appears one level below jobs:. In the case of the code you posted, the names would be foundry-test and ape-test.
